# Dirac Delta identity proof.

Tags: physics, dirac-delta

I was working on showing that: $$x \frac{\mathrm{d}(\delta (x))}{\mathrm{d}x} = -\delta(x)$$ using integration by parts. I arrived to a point where I had had as an answer the following: $$  -f(0) - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)x\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} \ \mathrm{d}x$$ I would greatly appreciate if someone could please provide an explanation as to why the second term is zero.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out the following link to help format your question.

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

It is zero because the integrand
$$\delta(x) x\frac{df}{dx}$$
is zero for all $x$.

If $x=0$ then it is obviously zero, and if $x\neq 0$ then it is also zero because $\delta(x)=0$.